# What is the right way to build when you are using db as container using compose file

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose

I am developing a spring boot application with postgres using docker file.

Dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:alpine-slim
ADD target/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=${ENV}", "/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: 'app:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - ENV=local
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=labuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=labpwd
```

to trigger the `docker-compose up` I must have jar in my target directory but jar build will fail as there's no database exist at that time.

I know it can be done by skipping the test like `./mvnw clean package -DskipTests` but then how these test will work when Prod Pipeline will run.

I might be missing something. Please suggest.

Regards

Comment: why build jar will fail if there are no DB ? Do you mean you have some tests that need to connect to an external DB for testing ?

Comment: @KenChan As of now there are no test but application has connection properties in application.properties. so it tries to make connection and getting failed.

Comment: docker-compose struggles with building images that require other containers to be available (like integration tests, ORMs, etc.). I recommend building your image outside of compose and only using compose to run the images.

Comment: @HansKilian could you please elaborate what do you mean by building the image outside.Can you please share more details on your approach ?

Comment: so your test does not require to test something with database but still need to start DB ? sounds like a smell to me... can you replace the external DB with some embeddable DB such as H2 or test container such that the test does not need an external DB to run ?

Comment: @Manish I mean setting up a build environment (i.e. running the database) and then using `docker build` to build the image.

Comment: @KenChan yeah Thanks, there was a default Test file in the generated the Spring boot app which was causing this issue, anyways after deletion that I am able to get the build (I was assuming buid uses those datasource properties but it doesn't)

Comment: @HansKilian yeah but that's a different setup altogether, here I want to run the db as container itself.

Comment: @Manish I was only suggesting doing the image build without compose. The running of the containers will work fine with compose.